# $W^{1,p}(\Omega) \hookrightarrow L^p(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and bounded. I want to show that  there is a compact embedding of the Sobolev space into $L^p$.
$$W^{1,p}(\Omega) \hookrightarrow L^p(\Omega)$$

I wanted to check if my reasoning is correct for the $p=n$ case.

I claim that, since the $L^p$ spaces are nested continuously, applying this fact to the function and its first order weak derivatives, we should have a continuous embedding
$$W^{1,n}(\Omega) \hookrightarrow W^{1,q}(\Omega), $$
for any $q \in [1,n)$. Then, we can apply Rellich-Kondrachov to get a compact embedding.

Is this the correct idea? I was wondering if, in particular, my claim $W^{1,n}(\Omega) \hookrightarrow W^{1,q}(\Omega)$ is correct?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the reasoning is correct, but you need $\Omega$ **to be a Lipschitz domain**, otherwise there are counterexamples where we fail even the embedding. Assuming a  Lipschitz boundary means you assume "some regularity" of the boundary.

Moreover, note how important is that $\Omega$ is bounded for these inclusions, otherwise all the "nested" spaces are no more nested and the reasoning fails: indeed give a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4103201/sobolev-spaces-embeddings-and-conjugate-exponents/4104500#4104500) where $\Omega$ is not bounded to see that your Sobolev embedding fails. Hence, your claim $W^{1,n}(\Omega) \hookrightarrow W^{1,q}(\Omega)$ is correct since $q \le n$, and actually note that another interesting question is if we can gain some integrability conditions by adding some "differentiability condition": see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4103201/sobolev-spaces-embeddings-and-conjugate-exponents/4104500#4104500) as well.

Let me add some references in cases you wanted to go deeper with some embeddings result:
“Giovanni Leoni - [*A first course in Sobolev Spaces*](https://www.google.it/books/edition/A_First_Course_in_Sobolev_Spaces/qoA8DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=leoni%20sobolev&pg=PR4&printsec=frontcover)”
“Adams - [*Sobolev Spaces*](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Sobolev_Spaces/R5A65Koh-EoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=leoni%20sobolev&printsec=frontcover)”.

Other two referenes, if you are interested in Sobolev Spaces from the point of view of PDEs then:

- Brezis’ book *[Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Functional_Analysis_Sobolev_Spaces_and_P/GAA2XqOIIGoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=brezis%20functional%20analysis&printsec=frontcover)* (mainly chapter 8 of the second edition)
- Evans’ book *[Partial Differential Equations](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Partial_Differential_Equations/Xnu0o_EJrCQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=evans%20partial%20differential%20equations&printsec=frontcover)* (mainly chapter 5 of the second edition).

Comment: thank you! This is brilliant and in-depth. Really appreciate the resources too. To clarify you say Hence, your claim $W^{1,n}(\Omega) \hookrightarrow W^{1,q}(\Omega)$ s correct since $q \le n$, so that is true even if all i know is $\Omega$ is bounded? Or does it have a cone property like you mention? (Wasn't quite sure since the linked question asks about $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: No worries, happy to help! :) In any case, this is true since if the weak gradient is in $L^n$ and $\Omega$ bdd, then the weak gradient is also in $L^q$ for $q \le n$ (it's just inclusion of $L^p$ spaces).